# Swift: How to use handoff in the simplest way possible?

Tags: swift, handoff

I am trying to use handoff to make an iphone app do something when the user does something in the watchkit app. In the watch app (in InterfaceController.swift), I have this code that gets run when the user taps a button:

```
self.updateUserActivity("com.test", userInfo: ["one":"two"], webpageURL: nil)
```

Then in the AppDelegate.swift file of the phone app, I have this code:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!,
        continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity!,
        restorationHandler: (([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!)
          -> Bool {

      let userInfo = userActivity.userInfo
      println("testing: \(userInfo)")
      return true
    }
```

In theory this should print the userInfo (in this case ["one":"two"]) to the console, but I think I'm missing something here.